# As a journalist, how can tipsters contact me about the story I'm writing before it's published?

Tags: resources, research, journalism

I'm a journalist who writes stories about niche topics. When I publish my stories, I always get great comments and news tips from people around the internet, which would have added a lot to the original story.

Is there a way that people with helpful news tips about a certain subject can find journalists writing stories about that subject, BEFORE the stories are actually published?

Comment: It would help to know what the niche topic is.  Is it a particular sub-culture?  Is it kosher in society?  Is it a focus on a certain news topic? On government?  On an industry?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a central place to do that.

But you can make your interest known. In a blog post and other social media, tell your fans what subject you are researching and solicit their tips. Perhaps make your "tip line" posts a featured part of your blog.

Of course, this reaches only your current fans, who may or may not have tips about your next subject.

Answer (score 1):

Journalists don't sit at home and wait for information to come to them. They talk to people. Finding the right people to talk to, and making them talk, is the specific skill of the journalist. Anyone can condense Google results into an article. There is even software that does that automatically. If you haven't yet learned the skill of *reporting* (that is, the information-gathering part of a journalist's job) you can study journalism at a university or at a journalist school. Teaching it to you in an answer is a bit beyond the scope of this site (and outside my expertise).

Comment: Lol I wasn't asking how to gather information, I was asking if there's a specific system in place for tipsters to find journalists with upcoming stories.

Comment: And I answered: The system is that *you* have to find *them*. If someone has some secret to share, they'll approach whatever newspaper or tv editorial office they find trustworthy. Outside of these cases journalists approach people that work in positions that have the knowledge they want. These relationships have to be built carefully and over time. It is a lot like the work of a secret service. There is no system where people can leave their information and anyone can retrieve it.

Comment: If you want to be one of the journalists that people turn to when they know things, you need to build a reputation. That's all the system there is.